# How can I force the `v-t` directive (or `v-text`) to replace only the `<slot/>` part of a component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I created a very simple Vue component that adds some content before and after the slot. Let's simplify it as:

```html
<template>
  <span> A <slot /> B </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>
```

It works well. For instance:

```html
<my-component>X</my-component>
```

renders:

```html
<span> A X B </span>
```

Then I start using `vue-i18n`'s `v-t` directive. It happens that `v-t` directive replaces all the `textContent`, like `v-text`.

How can I force the `v-t` directive (or `v-text`) to replace only the `<slot/>` part of a component?

Answer (score 1):

Apply the directive to a tag *inside* `<my-component>` (not on `<my-component>` itself):

```html
<!-- <my-component v-t="foo"> --> <!-- DON'T DO THIS -->
<my-component>
  <p v-t="foo"></p>
</my-component>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-vuei18n-j31ym?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark)